# Writing vectors in the $\hat{r}$ and $\hat{\theta}$ basis

Tags: vectors

I am having a bit of confusion about writing down vectors in the $\hat{r}$,  $\hat{\theta}$ basis. Let's say I want to write $-1$ $\hat{i}$ $+$ $1$ $\hat{j}$ in the $\hat{r}$,  $\hat{\theta}$ basis. Could I write $1$ $\hat{r}$ $+$ $1$ $\hat{\theta}$ so long as I specify that $\hat{r}$ is "at" $\pi/2$ radians? (...and in the above question $\hat{\theta}$ would be "at" $\pi$ radians)

Could I have described the exact same point with $\sqrt2\hat{r}$ $+$ $0$ $\hat{\theta}$ so long as I specify this time that $\hat{r}$ is "at" $3\pi/4$ radians? (...and $\hat{\theta}$ would be "at" $5\pi/4$ radians, but we wouldn't move along the $\hat{\theta}$  direction this time).

Comment: Why do you assume that all your readers will know what the "$\{\hat r, \hat \theta\}$ basis" means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do so.

Remember the vectors $\hat r,\hat\theta$ are defined by the equations
$$\begin{cases}\hat r=\cos\theta\hat i+\sin\theta\hat j\\ \hat\theta=-\sin\theta\hat i+\cos\theta\hat j.\end{cases}\tag{1}$$

This is equivalent to $$\begin{cases}\hat i=\cos\theta\hat r-\sin\theta\hat\theta\\ \hat j=\sin\theta\hat r+\cos\theta\hat\theta.\end{cases}\tag{2}$$

To see why this is true, remember that each of $\hat r,\hat\theta$ are obtained by rotating each of $\hat i,\hat j$ by $\theta$ radian anti-clockwise (which is what $(1)$ does). So we can rotate each of $\hat r,\hat\theta$ by $-\theta$ radian anti-clockwise to obtain $\hat i,\hat j$ (which is what $(2)$ does).

So $-1\hat i+1\hat j=-(\cos\theta\hat r-\sin\theta\hat\theta)+(\sin\theta\hat r+\cos\theta\hat\theta)=(\sin\theta-\cos\theta)\hat r+(\sin\theta+\cos\theta)\hat\theta$. Plug in the value $\theta$ and you can express $-1\hat i+1\hat j$ in terms of $\hat r,\hat\theta$.

For case 1, you put $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$, giving $(\sin\theta-\cos\theta)\hat r+(\sin\theta+\cos\theta)\hat\theta=\hat r+\hat\theta$. For case 2, you put $\theta=\frac{3\pi}{4}$, giving $(\sin\theta-\cos\theta)\hat r+(\sin\theta+\cos\theta)\hat\theta=\sqrt2\hat r$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think it is probably a fairly common misconception that the theta hat object is somehow intrinsically an angle... when the truth is that it is literally a unit vector that behaves exactly like i hat, j hat or any other unit vector. (Technically I suppose we could call it a unit vector valued function because the direction it points happens to have a dependency... I'm sure it doesn't help the misconceptions that the dependency happens to be on the polar coordinate theta).

Answer (score 0):

The question indeed originated in physics.stackexchange and the use of symbols here is very confusing. @edm considers $\hat{r}$, $\hat{\theta}$ and (i,j) as two cartesian coordinate systems where one is rotated by $\theta$ from the other. The symbols $\hat{x_1}$, $\hat{y_1}$, $\hat{x_2}$ and $\hat{y_2}$ can be applied just as well.

In physics, this coordinate system is usually related to a non-inertial system, for example a continuously rotating coordinate system following an object in circular motion. In that case, the object is always at r$\hat{r}$.

I usually refrain from using (r,$\theta$) in favor of (r,n) where n is a unit vector orthogonal to r. This clarifies the ambiguity between angle $\theta$ and vector $\theta$.

Comment: Your answer is very interesting. Are you saying that, in a rotation problem, the relevant polar coordinate at each tick of the clock is essentially just a generator of the appropriate placement/tilt of an instantaneous cartesian coordinate system with unit vectors $\hat r(\theta(t)),\hat\theta(\theta(t))$, or in your notation, $\hat x_1(\theta(t)),\hat x_2(\theta(t))$?

Comment: Actually, when adopt the rotating coordinate system, $\theta$, the angle measured in relation to a fixed cartesian  system, is of no interest to you. Suppose you are in the center of a rotating carousel and facing your friend standing at the rim. The carousel rotates, but he is always at $r\hat{r}$. If he lifts his hand sideways, his hand will point to $\hat{\theta}$ and from your point of view the fixed cartesian system does not need to exist. By the way, you do not need to go to the playground for that. Earth itself is a perfect example as well.

Answer (score -2):

You need a combination. You are correct in saying that your value of $\hat{r}$ needs to be $\sqrt{2}$, but by saying $0\hat{\theta}$ you are saying that your point lies in the $\hat{i}$ direction. Saying that it is "at" $3\pi /4$ radians is precisely what $3\pi /4 \hat{\theta}$ means.

Your answer in polar coordinates $(r, \theta)$ should be $\left(\sqrt2 , \frac{3\pi}{4}\right).$

Think of it in terms of $re^{i\theta} = r\cos\theta\hat{i} + r\sin\theta\hat{j}$

Comment: You answer is wrong. The vectors $\hat r, \hat\theta$ are orthonormal by assumption. So $\sqrt2\hat r+\frac{3\pi}{4}\hat\theta$ cannot be equal to $-1\hat i+1\hat j$ in any case, as their lengths are different. I know it is confusing. The notation is probably introduced in a physics course, and translating into a form that we understand takes quite an effort.

Comment: @edm In what way are their lengths different? If you move a length of $\sqrt2$ (from the origin) and an angle of $3\pi/4$ (from the $\hat{i}$ direction) then your result is _exactly_ the same place as if in Cartesian coordinates you move $-1$ in $\hat{i}$ and $1$ in $\hat{j}$.

Just try putting it into your calculator...

Comment: Norm of $\sqrt 2\hat r+\frac{3\pi}{4}\hat\theta$ is $\sqrt{\sqrt2^2+\left(\frac{3\pi}{4}\right)^2}$. Note that $\hat\theta$ is just a vector. It is not representing any rotation.

Comment: In Polar coordinates $\hat{\theta}$ represents rotation. The magnitude of a vector given in this form *IS* the value in front of $\hat{r}$.

Comment: $\theta$ is simply argument of exponential in complex number theory ...it represents rotation

Answer (score -2):

This is obviously a very old question but to consider $\hat{r}$ and $\hat{\theta}$ as a rotation transformation on $\hat{i}$ and $\hat{j}$ is terribly wrong. By your definition $\hat{r}$, $\hat{\theta}$, $\hat{i}$ and $\hat{j}$ all belong to the cartesian coordinate system, but you are giving the unit vector different names to refer to two Cartesian coordinate systems. If that’s what you are looking for, call them as $\hat{a}$ and $\hat{b}$ instead of $\hat{r}$ and $\hat{\theta}$.

You are wrongly handling the polar coordinates, which have the basis $\hat{r}$ and $\hat{\theta}$. If I were to write $-1\hat{i}+1\hat{j}$ in polar coordinate it indeed will be $\sqrt{2}\hat{r}+\frac{3\pi}{4}\hat{\theta}$. This is because fundamentally the polar coordinate interprets a vector through magnitude and angle. This thread does not debate this issue very well and as the person asking this question you have swiftly decided what is right or wrong. When you right $\hat{r}$ and $\hat{\theta}$, what are you referring to - basis vectors of a polar coordinate system or a new definition of basis vector as defined by the rotation matrix? It is also very wrong to say “it is a common misconception that $\hat{\theta}$ is intrinsically linked to angle.” $\hat{\theta}$ component refers to the angle of **a vector** whose magnitude is given by the magnitude of the $\hat{r}$ component. Both $\hat{r}$ and $\hat{\theta}$ are unit vectors.

Comment: You totally misunderstand. We are not giving polar coordinates for the point $(-1,1)$. At a given point with polar coordinates $(r,\theta)$, we are representing a (tangent) vector with respect to the basis $\hat r = (\cos\theta,\sin\theta), \hat\theta=(-\sin\theta,\cos\theta)$.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/2056209)